# Editing the contents of tuples

Tags: python

Hi please is there a way to edit the contents of this tuple residing in a nested list. I ask because my readings tell me  tuples are immutable. With what codes can the contents be upacked and edited:

This is what I mean, for n below

```
n = [[(14883, 14383), (14383, 14939)], [(14939, 6703), (6703, 7277)]]
```

Desired output is below:

```
m = [[(14883B, 14383B), (14383B, 14939B)], [(14939B, 6703B), (6703B, 7277B)]]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = []
for i,(k, v) in enumerate(n):
    n[i] = (str(k)+'B', str(v) + 'B')
    m.append(n[i])
```

Comment: please will this work when the tuple is inside a nested list? can you help me with that as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a new list of tuples with the updated values as follows:

```
m = [(str(val[0])+'B', str(val[1])+'B') for val in n]
```

This code uses list-comprehension and takes the values from the previous list and creates a **new** list with the 'B' added.

[EDIT:] You have updated your question. For the updated question, with the deeper level of nesting, I suggest modifying @doniyor's approach in his answer is a better way to do it.

Comment: please will this work when the tuple is inside a nested list? can you help me with that as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can`t edit tuple, but you can always do it like this

```
>>> def catify(data):
...     return (data[0],'cat')
...
>>> my_pet = ('Squiggly', 'dog')
>>> my_pet = catify(my_pet)
>>> print (my_pet)
("Squiggly','cat')
```